# How does background-attachment work with its children?

Tags: html, css, background-attachment

I was looking for how to generate the new glass morphism effect with CSS3. Afortunatelly I found [This article that make it happens](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-frosted-glass-effect-in-css--cms-32535?utm_campaign=yt_tutsplus_sLkBmV4yGJ4&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=youtube.com&utm_content=description). In the first method the article makes something like this (I wrote this code with the same structure and properties):

```sh
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: url(./bg.jpg) no-repeat; /*<------ check that I'm using a background image*/
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-attachment: fixed; /*<------ This is the most important part*/
}

.contenedor {
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: inherit; /*<------- Here the ".contenedor" element inherits its parent's background*/
  z-index: 2;
}
.contenedor::before {
  z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /*<------- Here the magic happens making a blur inside */
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

With this HTML:

```sh
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    TEXT INSIDE
  </div>
</body>
```

Now, I don't understand how the `background-attachment` works to mantain the background in the `.contenedor` element with `inherit` background.

I know that the `background:inherit` is to inherit all background properties from its parent, but what happen if I put

```sh
{
    ...
    background: url(./bg.jpg) no-repeat; /*<------ check that I'm using a background image*/
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed; /*<------ This is the most important part*/
    ...
}
```

instead `inherit`, It doesn't work.
PDT: Of course I understand the `::before` pseudoclass to achieve the background and I'm using the first methos instead the second because is not compatible with Mozilla Firefox

Thank you all and sorry about my poor English

Comment: your question is not clear. You want to understand how it works or why it doesn't work without inherit?

Comment: Thank you for your response, the code works, I would like to know why... I can't undersdant the point of background-attachment fixed because I have been used it just for parallax effect you know. Thanks